# Pixel-wise Standardized Precipitation Index (SPI) calculation of monthly rainfall raster in R

Tags: time-series, r-raster, ncdf4

I want to calculate Standardized Precipitation Index (SPI) of monthly rainfall raster in R. I have seen one question related to this in SO ([R Standardized Precipitation Index .nc file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49848437/r-standardized-precipitation-index-nc-file)), but it was not having any answers. So, I am putting a new question. I have downloaded the monthly rainfall data from the following source
https://crudata.uea.ac.uk/cru/data/hrg/cru_ts_4.03/cruts.1905011326.v4.03/pre/

I have read it in R using `raster` package.

```
library(raster)
file <- "cru_ts4.03.1901.2018.pre.dat.nc"
rain <- brick(file)
```

I know it can be done using `calc` function of `raster` package and for SPI calculation many packages are available in R (e.g. `spi`, `SPEI`, `precintcon`). I am able to calculate SPI for point data. But I am unable to use the `calc` function for SPI calculation of raster data. Now my question is how to calculate SPI on this raster at different time scales (1, 2, 3, 6, 12, 24)?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem yet? I need to calculate SPI for a raster.

Comment: No not yet.....

Comment: @BappaDas why don't you extract the values of each pixel as a vector and then do the standardized estimation?

Comment: @FelixPhl Can you please provide sample code?

Comment: @BappaDas I checked the above linked SO thread and there is an answer that does exactly what you want